# Escolher o Modal da variável

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

estou dando o valor para uma variável string no meu arquivo index.cs e depois estou pegando o valor para usar no TypeScript, porém eu estou criando outra pagina alem do index agora e está dando erro quando eu chamo a variável para ser usada no TS, eu gostaria de pegar a variável de um model específico, veja como eu estou fazendo:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var mensagem = "@Model.msg";</script>
```

porém desta maneira está cobrando do outro Model esta variável, e la não tem, então eu gostaria de pegar só do index, que seria +/- neste sentido, mas não exatamente como fazer:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var mensagem = "@Model.IndexModel.msg";</script>
```

se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Se possível edit a pergunta adicionando mais detalhes sobre como você esta fazendo, e onde esta esse trecho de código do exemplo.

Comment: não podia criar uma classe base com essa informação e herdar dela todas as models onde vai precisar? assim teria a informação em várias models e resolveria isso

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso não daria para ser pelo Model na View, você precisa usar ViewBag ou ViewData para setar a informação que precisa no seu OnPost() e receber ela na sua outra View.

Exemplo:

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult OnPost() {
    ViewBag.MsgErro = "Mensagem de erro";
}
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mensagem = '@ViewBag.MsgErro';
    alert(mensagem);
</script>
```

Caso queira uma explicação mais afundo do funcionamento das ViewBag e ViewData, indico o [conteúdo do Eduardo Pires](https://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/06/asp-net-mvc-viewdata-viewbag-tempdata/).

Answer (score 0):

Trabalhei pouco com o ASP.NET, mas deveria ser algo parecido com o que você digitou. Que eu saiba, para pegar uma variável de um model, deve-se usar

```
@Model."Nome do Model"."Nome da variável";
```

Mas sem usar aspas, eu identificava em uma outra parte do código, algo semelhante à isso:

```
@{var price=50;}
<html>
<body>
@if (price>30)
{
<p>The price is too high.</p>
}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Então seria como eu coloquei la mesmo, certo?? `var mensagem = "@Model.IndexModel.msg";`, mas infelizmente não está funcionando... também pensei que seria assim, mas não funcionou. :/

Comment: O ASP.NET funciona de forma parecida com o JavaScript, onde vai ter uma parte separada do código para você definir essas funções

Comment: Isso não funcionaria pra mim... O que acontece é o seguinte, dentro do meu método OnPost(), eu chamo outro método, que me retorna uma string, se ocorrer algum erro, e se não ocorrer, não vai retornar nada dessa string... vai apenas seguir para o próximo passo. e dependendo, se retornar a string, eu devo mostrá-la para o usuário e não seguir para a próxima página... É uma tela de login né... então eu verifico os dados, e dependendo ele não pode acessar

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais facil de fazer isso e pela sessao

EXEMPLO:

```
Criando uma Session na sua pagina index.cs: 
Session["nomeSession"] = "aqui você pega valor que você deseja passar pra outra pagina"; 

Lendo uma Session: 
String strValorSession = Session["nomeSession"];
```

mais informações no lik: https://www.codigofonte.net/dicas/csharp/80_trabalhando-com-session-em-c